# BitmapSource to UI Element for FixedDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf, fixeddocument

I have the following in a WPF application:

1. Create a stackpanel
2. Create a bitmapsource from the
   stackpanel
3. Create a FixedDocument

So, I'm trying to get from step 2 to step 3. FixedDocuments only accept UIElement objects for Children.Add. Is there a way to get from a bitmapsource to a UIElement (or some other object) that will be accepted by a FixedDocuemnt? Yes, I realize that a Stackpanel is a UIElement and I could add that to my document but I prefer to add it as an image.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for `System.Windows.Controls.Image`. Given `BitmapSource bs`

```
Image anImage = new Image();
anImage.Source = bs;
```

should do the trick to get from 2. to 3.